# determine if subset is subspace of $ℝ^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

$a)$ $(a,b,c)$ where $a+b+c= 1$

$b)$ $(a,b,c)$ where $a-3b+c=0$

$c)$ $(a,a+1,b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are any real numbers

$d)$ $(a,b,c)$ where $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 =1$.

I understand that there are thee properties that you much check for however i am not sure if i am applying them correctly.

$1)$ $0$ is there

$2)$ Closed by addition of vectors

$3)$ Closed by multiplication of real-valued scalar

The answers that I got are ( i am not sure if they are correct):

$1)$ no 
$2)$ yes 
$3)$ no 
$4)$ yes

how can i correctly apply these principles and check my work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) The zero vector is not there.

b) The zero vector is there. If $[a,b,c],[d,e,f]$ are vectors where $a - 3b + c = 0 = d - 3e + f$, then for any scalar $\lambda$,
$$ (a - 3b + c) + \lambda (d - 3e + f) = 0
$$
Hence all three axioms are satisfied and (b) is a subspace.

c) The zero vector is not there.

d) The zero vector is not there.

Comment: in a) : $a+b+c=1$ and  not $0$ hence it is not a subspace

Comment: @stity If you had seen the edit history, you would know that OP changed the $0$ on $a + b + c = 0$ to $1$.

Comment: anyway your answer was  wrong and needed an edit. Now that it is correct I upvoted it.